# Evasion checks for investigator attacking a monster in a space with another monster

Tags: mansions-of-madness

If an investigator is in a space with two monsters (A, B) and attacks one (A) of them, does he have to make an evasion check for the one (B) which he is not attacking?

The rules don't explicitly confirm nor deny this, and it seems sensible to play this way, but I would like to have the opinion of some more experienced keeper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, you do not perform an evade test on either monster when performing an attack action.**

The [rules](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/mansions-of-madness/support/MansionsOfMadnessLoRes.pdf) are explicit on this (page 14):

> **Evade Tests** - An investigator must make an evade test against every monster in his space **before moving** or **performing non-attack** actions.
>
> An evade test is an attribute test that is resolved immediately before the investigator attempts to move or take the action. In order to evade a monster, the player makes a Dexterity test modified by the monster’s awareness (the white number at the top right corner of the monster’s token).
>
> If the player passes this test, then the investigator suffers no ill effect. If he fails this test, the keeper may have the monster damage the investigator (equal to the monster’s damage value – see page 23). Regardless of whether he passes or fails, the investigator may then move or perform the intended action. After having attempted to evade a monster, the investigator may freely move and take actions without having to try to evade the same monster that turn.

It specifically allows attacking on page 15:

> **Attacking a monster does not require making an evade test.** This attack may be unarmed, with a weapon, or with an “attack” Spell card. This attack does not need to target a monster in the investigator’s space.

or again on page 9:

> Attacking a monster is the only action that an investigator can perform while a monster is in his space (unless he evades the monster, see “Evade Tests” on page 14).

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, though.  The OP knows how evade checks/attacks work, but was wondering what happens if there are multiple monsters in a space.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that he does not need to make an evasion check for the second monster.
Evasion checks are to be made when you try to move from or search in space where there is a monster.

Comment: An evade check would be required if they wanted to do anything but attack while in the room with any monster, and would have to do as many evade checks as there are monsters.

Answer (score 0):

Evasion checks are required when you are in a space with a monster and attempt to perform a non-attack action.

In your example, lets say you start in the room with two monsters so you can have two actions this turn.

If you spend your first action attacking one of the monsters, you do *not* require an evade check against it.  If you spend your second action attacking either of the monsters, again  you do *not* require an evade check.

However, if you want to spend your second action searching/moving/doing anything but an attack action against either monster, you *do* need to do an evade check against *both monsters* (if you didn't kill the first during the attack action), since they are both still in the room.

On the other hand, if you spent your first action entering the room, and the second action attacking - then there is no reason to do an evade check since you are not doing any non-attack actions.

In most MoM scenarios, there are only ever a few monsters on the board, so this particular situation shouldn't come up too often, but yeah - multiple monsters in one room can spell bad things for the investigators!

Comment: What second action are you talking about ? Each investigator only have one action (and two movements) per turn.